# How do I get the raw data behind this WSJ

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping, finance, quantitative-finance

I'm looking at 
http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/npage/2_3051.html?mod=mdc_h_dtabnk&symb=DJIA#IndexComponents

and wondering if there is a way to get hold of the data that wsj is showing, preferably without breaking the law to much.

I'm trying to get the minut data that is used in the java-applet for drawing the graphs.

I would like to try running some machine learning algorithms on the data, but I'm no expert on JavaScript and have no idea how to get to the actual data.

Doea anyone have any ideas?

Comment: which part? graph? components?

Comment: I'm  sorry, the data that I'm looking for is the data used to draw the graph in the Java Applet.

Comment: I have no idea what the legal ramifications are, but this is from their [Subscriber Agreement](http://online.wsj.com/public/page/subscriber_agreement.html): "You agree not to create abstracts from, scrape or display our content for use on another web site or service"

Comment: @sdleihssirhc I thourght there might be something like that - I'm only intending to use it for personal experiments, if my work bears fruit I will buy some 'real' data. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are financial APIs that you can get some pricing data from:

http://code.google.com/apis/finance/docs/finance-gadgets.html

http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/YahooFinanceAPIs

and I'm sure there are others out there. Or do you literally need their exact data source?